# How to find the set of indices where two vectors have equal elements in Python

Tags: python, numpy, vector

I have two vectors in Python: `Predictions` and `Labels`. What I would like to do is to find out the set of indices where these two vectors have equal elements. For example, lets say the vectors are:

```
Predictions = [4, 2, 5, 8, 3, 4, 2, 2]

     Labels = [4, 3, 4, 8, 2, 2, 1, 2]
```

So the set of indices where the two vectors have equal elements would be:

```
Indices = [0, 3, 7]
```

How can I get this in Python? Without using for-loops etc. Is there a built-in function for example in `numpy`?

Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is one way of doing it with numpy:

```
np.where(np.equal(Predictions, Labels))
```

which is equivalent to:

```
np.equal(Predictions, Labels).nonzero()
```

It will return a single element tuple though, so to get the actual array, add `[0]` as in:

```
np.equal(Predictions, Labels).nonzero()[0]
```

Comment: Thank you for your help =) Appreciate it

Answer (score 5):

For two arrays `a, b` with:

```
a = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
b = np.array([1, 3, 2, 4, 5])
```

`np.equal(a,b)` has the same output as `a==b` (which is easier to understand at first, I think):

```
> array([ True, False, False,  True,  True], dtype=bool)
```

The elements are checked element-wise and then an array of booleans is created.

`np.where()` checks some condition element-wise on an array:

```
np.where(a > 2)
> (array([2, 3, 4]),)
```

So combining `np.where` and `np.equal` is the thing you want:

```
np.where(np.equal(a,b))
> (array([0, 3, 4]),)
```

**edit**: nevermind, just saw that I were far too slow ^^

Comment: Thank you, appreciate your help :)